# permission, permission sets, XML, objects

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, xml

Lets assume that I created an object in DEV, several permissions respect to that object were set -not necessarily by me- and now this object is deployed to production. If I want to retrieve all the information like field permissions, accessibility ones, etc etc, I know that information will be in the profiles and in the permissionSets folder. What I don't know is all the xml element types used to specify this information. Does anyone know this? What could be the case for classes?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the appropriate values in the [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) object. The XML looks like:

```
<Profile ...>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>MyClass</apexClass>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
</Profile>
```

You can get the values currently in production with a package.xml file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <apiVersion>36.0</apiVersion>
</Package>
```

When you retrieve a profile, permissions for other items in the package.xml are also retrieved for the specified profiles.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE, Right click on your project folder -> Hover over the "Force.com" menu -> Select Add/Remove Metadata Components -> Click on the Add/Remove button -> Click the "Refresh" Icon, then uncheck and recheck the folders you want in your project.

You can also try to extract ALL the classes  by using the '*' in the package.xml file.

```
<types>
<member>*</member>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
```